# How do you add function guides to python when writing a module?

Tags: python, python-3.x, function, functional-programming, python-idle

I was recently writing a python module with many functions, and I was wondering if it was possible, and if so, how can I implement these function guides as shown in the picture below. Thanks in advance!

[image]

Comment: Just to note that to display the tooltip (in your screenshot), this is a feature of the shell. If you are writing code in another program, you may not get those hints.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

These are [function docstring](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0257/)s, to define them when writing a function, simply add a multi-line string to the start of the function

```
def function():
    '''This function does nothing'''
    pass
```

To access the docstring, use `function.__doc__` or `help(function)`

Comment: I have these docstrings in my functions, although none of them display when opening the brackets (refer to the picture in original question)

Comment: @Jake As Burhan Khalid said, tooltips are features of your editor or IDE. However, I do get tooltips on IDLE [image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hXY79.png)